# A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods in a 2D endlessrunner

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, error-handling

Hi i make a 2D endlessrunner and now im write the script for an obstacelspawner but an error is still there.
here is the code for the spawner

```
IEnumerator SpawnRandomObstacle()   
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(1.5f, 4.5f));
    int index = Random.Range(0, obstaclesToSpawn.Count);
    while (true)
    {
        if (!obstacleToSpawn[index].activeInHierarchy)
        {
            obstaclesToSpawn[index].SetActive(true);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            index = Random.Range(0, obstaclesToSpawn.Count);
        }
    }

    StartCoroutine (SpawnRandomObstacle ());
}
```

Comment: What’s the error. Can’t speculate without error output from debugger console window.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your method/coroutine inside a  monobehaviour class:

```
public class TrainingManagerEditorFreeRouteManager : MonoBehaviour {

    IEnumerator SpawnRandomObstacle()   
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(1.5f, 4.5f));
        int index = Random.Range(0, obstaclesToSpawn.Count);
        while (true)
        {
            if (!obstacleToSpawn[index].activeInHierarchy)
            {
                obstaclesToSpawn[index].SetActive(true);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                index = Random.Range(0, obstaclesToSpawn.Count);
            }
        }

        StartCoroutine (SpawnRandomObstacle ());
    }      
}
```

For a better understanding you can read what [namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/namespace) are. They're used as scopes to organize your code. If you dont put any, its the globall namespace, and you cannot put methods/corroutenes directly there.